# Are quotation marks needed when calling out specific words from a passage?

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks

Excerpt: In developed countries, running water is available everywhere and air-conditioning is expected not just in our homes but in our cars. We don't realize that these are luxuries.

My sentence: The author mentions "running water" and "air-conditioning" as examples of things we take for granted.

Are the quotation marks required?

Comment: No. In fact, your use of quotes makes it seem like you don't believe the author was actually referring to running water and air-conditioning. You seem to be using them as *scare quotes*.

Comment: Although your sentence would benefit from some other structure or punctuation, as *running water is available everywhere and air-conditioning is expected not just in our homes but in our cars* is a bit of a slab otherwise.

Comment: It's not cut and dried. The quote marks seem unnecessary to me in your case, I think due to the cue "The author mentions" coupled with the natural 'fit' of "running water" and "air-conditioning" in your sample sentence. The same words in my preceding sentence aren't a natural part of the sentence, hence the use of quote marks here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually kind of tricky: you want to guide your reader as much as possible without making him search for the connections between your text and the original text. You also want to give credit to the author as much as possible without paraphrasing.

But at the same time, "running water" and "air-conditioning" are pretty common expressions and short quotes. Plus, they are not the main point of the author. I don't think your text would suffer if you didn't put quotation marks, nor would it cause prejudice to the author.

> The author mentions running water and air-conditioning as examples of things we take for granted.

Seems fine to me (but please don't take my word for it !).

If you **did** want to give credit to the author, I would recommend giving it for the point he's making (for example, by quoting the part where he says these commodities are **luxuries**).